# Selenium-Webdriver (Java) failing to execute 'hoverover and click' function consistently

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, hover, action, mouseover

I'm trying to access a screen in an application, which appears when I do a mouse-hover over a tab and click on one of the options. I used Actions method to execute this using selenium. Here's my code:

```
element=driver.findElement(By.id("tab"));
Actions hoverover=new Actions(driver);
hoverover.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("menu"))).click().build().perform();
```

When I login to the application and directly call this tab, I'm able to access this without any issue. But the problem occurs when I access this tab from a different screen in the application.

Whenever I access the hover-over page from a different page in the application, sometimes the page loads correctly but most of the time it fails and I recieve 'no such element' or 'stale element reference' error.

I'm really not sure how it is able to access the tab without any issue sometimes and how sometimes it is throwing errors. Please guide me here and let me know if there is anything else(any additional functions/or an alternative to Actions?) I can do so that the mouse-over click works all the time.

EDIT: I tried using both Explicit and Implicit waits and even thread.sleep as well, but in vain. In Chrome(only in chrome) when i do a manual screen refresh while it tries to access the tab, it works. But when I do the same in my code [driver.navigate().refresh()], it's not working!!

Comment: Did you try explicit wait until element load?

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to mention that in the question. Added now. No, Explicit wait until element load also not working here.

Answer (score 0):

The stale element exception is probably occurring between when you set element and when you hoverover. Selenium does something like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("tab"));
// "element" has been set
Actions hoverover=new Actions(driver);
// Between here and hoverover, "element" has changed on the DOM
hoverover.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(
    driver.findElement(By.id("menu"))).click().build().perform();
// Uh-oh, what's "element?" Better throw an exception!
```

Try eliminating the element= line and moving driver.findElement to the inside of moveToElement().

```
Actions hoverover = new Actions(driver);
hoverover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("tab")))
    .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("menu"))).click().build().perform();
```

You could also try throwing in a WebDriverWait between hovering over tab and menu.

```
hoverover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("tab"))).build().perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("menu")));
hoverover.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("menu"))).click().build().perform();
```